Huggingface Custom Pipeline + Langchain Question
I'm developing a RAG POC using Langchain. My project builds a custom huggingface pipeline(subclass of TextGenerationPipeline) and inferences with the pipeline are fine. But when I trying to build a chain with it, langchain does not support it. I'm kinda stuck here.
What I did is:
from transformers import pipeline
import langchain
from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline

custom_pipe = transformers.pipeline(
    "custom_pipe",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    ...
)

my_llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=custom_pipe)

chain=prompt | my_llm

chain.invoke({"question":"How to cook a steak?"})

And it gives me error:
ValueError: Got invalid task custom_pipe, currently only ('text2text-generation', 'text-generation', 'summarization', 'translation') are supported
Any ideas on how to build chain with custom huggingface pipes?
